# self.extendedからbase.class_evalでインスタンス変数を初期化するのはなぜ？

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Railsのソースを読むと、

ActiveSupportのAutoloadで、

以下のようなコードがありました。

```
def self.extended(base) # :nodoc:
      base.class_eval do
        @_autoloads = {}
        @_under_path = nil
        @_at_path = nil
        @_eager_autoload = false
      end
end
```

extendされた際に、そのクラスに対して

クラスインスタンス変数を定義しているのですが

クラス変数を利用していないのは何故でしょうか？

クラスインスタンス変数とは違い、
クラス変数の場合は、継承先で親の変数を参照できるため、
上記のコードと同じ動作になると思っています。

Comment: `なぜ`という質問が広範すぎて、回答が難しく思います。普通は〇〇のように書くと思うが、なぜなのか？など、ここを不思議に思っている、という焦点を明確にできないでしょうか？理解は有っていると思います。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。
クラス変数、クラスインスタンス変数、インスタンス変数の理解が足りておらず、問題のコードは、インスタンス変数を定義しているものと思っておりましたが、クラスインスタンス変数を定義しているものだと理解致しました。ご指摘内容と上記を考慮して質問を 編集致します。

Answer (score 1):

自己解決致しました。

extendする際、クラス変数だと継承先で参照できないため、
self.extendedで、継承先にクラスインスタンス変数を定義していました。